# Error when I load RDF file in Web Services using class Model in Jena

Tags: java, web-services, rdf, jena, invocationtargetexception

I have a question:

I would like to load a RDF file in my WebService.

I have written this code:

```
@WebService(serviceName = "Prova_WS")
@Stateless()
public class Prova_WS{

    /**
     * Web service operation
     * @param f
     * @param label
     * @return 
     */
    @WebMethod(operationName = "operation")
    public String operation(@WebParam(name = "f") String f) {
        Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
        InputStream in = FileManager.get().open( f );

        // read the RDF/XML file
        model.read(in, "");
        ResIterator sublist = model.listSubjects();
        Resource sub = null;
        while (sublist.hasNext()){
           sub = sublist.next();
           break;
        }

        return sub.toString();
    }
}
```

I have done "Clean and Build", "Deploy" and "Test WebService" operations, but I get this error when I insert this value to the operation: "C:/prova.rdf" (without "").

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at org.glassfish.webservices.monitoring.WebServiceTesterServlet.doPost(WebServiceTesterServlet.java:336) at org.glassfish.webservices.monitoring.WebServiceTesterServlet.invoke(WebServiceTesterServlet.java:106) at org.glassfish.webservices.EjbWebServiceServlet.service(EjbWebServiceServlet.java:136) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) at org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.ServletHandler.doServletService(ServletHandler.java:242) at org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.ServletHandler.service(ServletHandler.java:193) at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246) at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191) at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168) at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189) at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119) at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288) at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206) at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136) at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114) at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77) at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838) at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113) at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115) at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55) at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135) at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564) at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) at org.glassfish.webservices.monitoring.WebServiceTesterServlet.doPost(WebServiceTesterServlet.java:307) ... 23 more Caused by: java.lang.Error: javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Unable to create SAAJ meta-factoryProvider com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl not found at com.sun.xml.ws.api.SOAPVersion.getSOAPFactory(SOAPVersion.java:210) at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP11Fault.java:184) at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:125) at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.StubHandler.readResponse(StubHandler.java:253) at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:181) at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:258) at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:117) at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:91) at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:154) at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy314.operation(Unknown Source) ... 28 more Caused by: javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Unable to create SAAJ meta-factoryProvider com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl not found at javax.xml.soap.SAAJMetaFactory.getInstance(SAAJMetaFactory.java:94) at javax.xml.soap.SOAPFactory.newInstance(SOAPFactory.java:296) at com.sun.xml.ws.api.message.saaj.SAAJFactory.createSOAPFactory(SAAJFactory.java:256) at com.sun.xml.ws.api.message.saaj.SAAJFactory.getSOAPFactory(SAAJFactory.java:131) at com.sun.xml.ws.api.SOAPVersion.getSOAPFactory(SOAPVersion.java:208) ... 37 more
```

UPDATE: In the GlassFish server 4, I read this error:

```
Grave:   log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.jena.riot.stream.JenaIOEnvironment).
Grave:   log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Grave:   log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Grave:   javax.ejb.EJBException
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.processSystemException(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:748)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.completeNewTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:698)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:503)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4475)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.WebServiceInvocationHandler.invoke(WebServiceInvocationHandler.java:205)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy296.operation(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.InvokerImpl.invoke(InvokerImpl.java:82)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.EjbInvokerImpl.invoke(EjbInvokerImpl.java:82)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(InvokerTube.java:149)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTube.java:88)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.AbstractTubeImpl.process(AbstractTubeImpl.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.MonitoringPipe.process(MonitoringPipe.java:142)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.PipeAdapter.processRequest(PipeAdapter.java:119)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.AbstractTubeImpl.process(AbstractTubeImpl.java:136)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.webservices.CommonServerSecurityPipe.processRequest(CommonServerSecurityPipe.java:210)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.webservices.CommonServerSecurityPipe.process(CommonServerSecurityPipe.java:142)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.PipeAdapter.processRequest(PipeAdapter.java:119)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:420)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:687)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:266)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:169)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.Ejb3MessageDispatcher.handlePost(Ejb3MessageDispatcher.java:110)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.Ejb3MessageDispatcher.invoke(Ejb3MessageDispatcher.java:80)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.EjbWebServiceServlet.dispatchToEjbEndpoint(EjbWebServiceServlet.java:203)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.EjbWebServiceServlet.service(EjbWebServiceServlet.java:146)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.ServletHandler.doServletService(ServletHandler.java:242)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.ServletHandler.service(ServletHandler.java:193)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xerces/util/XMLChar
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.Util.notNameChar(Util.java:108)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.Util.splitNamespace(Util.java:66)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.graph.Node_URI.getLocalName(Node_URI.java:75)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.ResourceImpl.getLocalName(ResourceImpl.java:150)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.PropertyImpl.checkLocalName(PropertyImpl.java:65)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.PropertyImpl.<init>(PropertyImpl.java:73)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ResourceFactory$Impl.createProperty(ResourceFactory.java:301)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ResourceFactory.createProperty(ResourceFactory.java:156)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.vocabulary.RDF.property(RDF.java:42)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.vocabulary.RDF.<clinit>(RDF.java:55)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.impl.OntResourceImpl.<clinit>(OntResourceImpl.java:58)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.enhanced.BuiltinPersonalities.<clinit>(BuiltinPersonalities.java:37)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.ModelCom.<init>(ModelCom.java:70)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory.createDefaultModel(ModelFactory.java:140)
    at prova.Prova_WS.operation(Prova_WS.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4695)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:630)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4667)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4655)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.WebServiceInvocationHandler.invoke(WebServiceInvocationHandler.java:193)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xerces.util.XMLChar
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1761)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1611)
    ... 103 more

Avvertenza:   EJB5184:A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB Linker_WS, method: public java.lang.String linker.Prova_WS.operation(java.lang.String)
Avvertenza:   javax.ejb.EJBException
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.processSystemException(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:748)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.completeNewTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:698)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:503)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4475)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.WebServiceInvocationHandler.invoke(WebServiceInvocationHandler.java:205)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy296.operation(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.InvokerImpl.invoke(InvokerImpl.java:82)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.EjbInvokerImpl.invoke(EjbInvokerImpl.java:82)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(InvokerTube.java:149)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTube.java:88)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.AbstractTubeImpl.process(AbstractTubeImpl.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.MonitoringPipe.process(MonitoringPipe.java:142)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.PipeAdapter.processRequest(PipeAdapter.java:119)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.AbstractTubeImpl.process(AbstractTubeImpl.java:136)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.webservices.CommonServerSecurityPipe.processRequest(CommonServerSecurityPipe.java:210)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.webservices.CommonServerSecurityPipe.process(CommonServerSecurityPipe.java:142)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.PipeAdapter.processRequest(PipeAdapter.java:119)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:420)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:687)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:266)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:169)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.Ejb3MessageDispatcher.handlePost(Ejb3MessageDispatcher.java:110)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.Ejb3MessageDispatcher.invoke(Ejb3MessageDispatcher.java:80)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.EjbWebServiceServlet.dispatchToEjbEndpoint(EjbWebServiceServlet.java:203)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.EjbWebServiceServlet.service(EjbWebServiceServlet.java:146)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.ServletHandler.doServletService(ServletHandler.java:242)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.ServletHandler.service(ServletHandler.java:193)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xerces/util/XMLChar
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.Util.notNameChar(Util.java:108)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.Util.splitNamespace(Util.java:66)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.graph.Node_URI.getLocalName(Node_URI.java:75)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.ResourceImpl.getLocalName(ResourceImpl.java:150)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.PropertyImpl.checkLocalName(PropertyImpl.java:65)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.PropertyImpl.<init>(PropertyImpl.java:73)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ResourceFactory$Impl.createProperty(ResourceFactory.java:301)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ResourceFactory.createProperty(ResourceFactory.java:156)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.vocabulary.RDF.property(RDF.java:42)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.vocabulary.RDF.<clinit>(RDF.java:55)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.impl.OntResourceImpl.<clinit>(OntResourceImpl.java:58)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.enhanced.BuiltinPersonalities.<clinit>(BuiltinPersonalities.java:37)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.ModelCom.<init>(ModelCom.java:70)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory.createDefaultModel(ModelFactory.java:140)
    at prova.Prova_WS.operation(Prova_WS.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4695)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:630)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4667)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4655)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.WebServiceInvocationHandler.invoke(WebServiceInvocationHandler.java:193)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xerces.util.XMLChar
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1761)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1611)
    ... 103 more
```

Why? I know that "C:/prova.rdf" is not empty. What am I wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's executing

```
Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
```

and giving:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xerces.util.XMLChar
```

That suggests the Xerces jars (xercesImpl -- also needs xml-apis) are not on the runtime class path.

It's better to use "file:C:/prova.rdf" but that isn't the issue here - it isn't at that point.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't have add the Xerces jars in the runtime class path.